# Select all rows where a column value occurs more than once

Tags: postgresql

I have a following table structure in Postgres:

```
 id | account_id | plan_id | active
----+------------+---------+--------
  1 |    0cYd7Ak |       1 |      f
  2 |    Uk02q1d |       1 |      t
  3 |    eRlk810 |       2 |      f
  4 |    Uk02q1d |       2 |      t
  5 |    0cYd7Ak |       1 |      t
  6 |    yT3nv3p |       3 |      t
```

How I can select all row where `account_id` occurs more than once? For the example above it will return rows 1, 2, 4, 5

I tried this one query, but it does not return what I expect:

```
select * from table_name t1 
where (select count(*) from table_name t2 
  where t1.account_id = t2.account_id) > 1 
order by t1.account_id;
```

Comment: There are many ways to write this but your query seems correct. What results do you get?

Comment: Ooops. You are right! It works. Unfortunately I tested this query yesterday night and probably was to tired to understood that it returns exactly what I need.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9736944/6064933

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query seems correct (although it may not be the most efficient).

There are many ways to write this type of query. For example, you could use `EXISTS` to avoid counting in the correlated subquery:

```
select * from table_name t1 
where exists 
      (select 1 from table_name t2 
       where t1.account_id = t2.account_id and t1.id <> t2.id) 
 ;
```

Another method is to use a subquery or CTE and window aggregate:

```
select id, account_id, plan_id, active
from 
  ( select *, 
           count(1) over (partition by account_id) as occurs
    from table_name
  ) AS t 
where occurs > 1 ;
```

Or use a subquery to find the accounts that have more than one occurrences and then join to the table:

```
select t.*
from 
  ( select account_id
    from table_name
    group by account_id
    -- having count(1) > 1          
    having min(id) <> max(id)      -- variation with same result 
  ) as c
  join table_name as t 
  on t.account_id = c.account_id ;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also try with `HAVING` clause.

```
select account_id, count(id) as repetita
from t1
group by account_id

having count(id) > 1 ;
```

with this solution remember to add the field you want to output to `group by` also